# Executing kafka-stream example with eclipse, fails with UnsatisfiedLinkError for librocksdbjni.dll (Can't find dependency)

Tags: java, eclipse, apache-kafka

I am trying to run a kafka-stream wordcount example with eclipse IDE but getting following error:
I have added  0.10.1.0 kafka-client and 0.10.1.0 kafka-stream as dependency in my pom file. I have also checked the dependency tree and it's using rocksdbjni-4.9 jar. Based on some read on internet, this issue has been fixed on 0.10.1.0 version of kafka  but I am still getting.
Any help?

```
Exception in thread "StreamThread-1" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Local\Temp\librocksdbjni6935746072594020003.dll: Can't find dependent libraries
    at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1937)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1822)
    at java.lang.Runtime.load0(Runtime.java:809)
    at java.lang.System.load(System.java:1086)
    at org.rocksdb.NativeLibraryLoader.loadLibraryFromJar(NativeLibraryLoader.java:78)
    at org.rocksdb.NativeLibraryLoader.loadLibrary(NativeLibraryLoader.java:56)
    at org.rocksdb.RocksDB.loadLibrary(RocksDB.java:47)
    at org.rocksdb.RocksDB.<clinit>(RocksDB.java:23)
    at org.rocksdb.Options.<clinit>(Options.java:21)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.RocksDBStore.<init>(RocksDBStore.java:127)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.RocksDBStore.<init>(RocksDBStore.java:112)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.RocksDBKeyValueStoreSupplier.get(RocksDBKeyValueStoreSupplier.java:56)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.TopologyBuilder.build(TopologyBuilder.java:787)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.TopologyBuilder.build(TopologyBuilder.java:761)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.createStreamTask(StreamThread.java:631)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.addStreamTasks(StreamThread.java:660)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.access$100(StreamThread.java:69)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread$1.onPartitionsAssigned(StreamThread.java:124)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator.onJoinComplete(ConsumerCoordinator.java:228)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator.joinGroupIfNeeded(AbstractCoordinator.java:313)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator.ensureActiveGroup(AbstractCoordinator.java:277)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator.poll(ConsumerCoordinator.java:259)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.pollOnce(KafkaConsumer.java:1013)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.poll(KafkaConsumer.java:979)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.runLoop(StreamThread.java:407)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.run(StreamThread.java:242)
```

Answer (score 0):

Windows is not officially supported, yet.

However, Rocksdb 4.9.0+ releases should have a Windows DLL build and should work out of the box.

For older versions, there is also as workaround as described here: http://search-hadoop.com/m/Kafka/uyzND13pNzscClkW1?subj=Re+Kafka+Streams+on+Windows+

Comment: HI @Matthias. Where can I find the Rocksdb DLL? I cloned the Rocksdb repository but no compiled library is present

Comment: You need to build it the project as described here: https://github.com/facebook/rocksdb/wiki/RocksJava-Basics

Answer (score 0):

Installing vc_redist.x64 from https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48145 helped to resolve the issue.  I was facing same issue in Windows10 home edition

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this by adding the following dependency to my pom.xml:

`<dependency><groupId>org.rocksdb</groupId><artifactId>rocksdbjni</artifactId><version>6.29.5</version></dependency>`