# Apache kafka WordCountDemo Error On Windows

Tags: java, apache-kafka

I am using kafka 1.0.0 on windows 7 with JAVA 8.
Using the commands as mentioned in the demo at official site, I am able to start my zookeeper, kafka server, my topics, and producers and consumers.

But when I execute the command for starting my stream i.e my WordCountDemo class with below command

bin\windows\kafka-run-class.bat org.apache.kafka.streams.examples.wordcount.WordCountDemo

I see below exception in the command prompt.

D:\kafka-1.0.0\kafka_2.11-1.0.0>bin\windows\kafka-run-class.bat org.apache.kafka
    .streams.examples.wordcount.WordCountDemo

```
[2018-03-06 00:17:39,501] WARN stream-client [streams-wordcount-5854a7f0-b0c1-43
    a0-93de-6eb79e75d123]All stream threads have died. The instance will be in error
    state and should be closed. (org.apache.kafka.streams.KafkaStreams)
    Exception in thread "streams-wordcount-5854a7f0-b0c1-43a0-93de-6eb79e75d123-Stre
    amThread-1" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: C:\Users\kaul_s\AppData\Local\Temp\l
    ibrocksdbjni1616257841244012086.dll: Can't find dependent libraries
            at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1938)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1821)
            at java.lang.Runtime.load0(Runtime.java:809)
            at java.lang.System.load(System.java:1086)
            at org.rocksdb.NativeLibraryLoader.loadLibraryFromJar(NativeLibraryLoade
    r.java:78)
            at org.rocksdb.NativeLibraryLoader.loadLibrary(NativeLibraryLoader.java:
    56)
            at org.rocksdb.RocksDB.loadLibrary(RocksDB.java:64)
            at org.rocksdb.RocksDB.<clinit>(RocksDB.java:35)
            at org.rocksdb.Options.<clinit>(Options.java:25)
            at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.RocksDBStore.openDB(RocksDBS
    tore.java:128)
            at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.RocksDBStore.init(RocksDBSto
    re.java:185)
            at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.ChangeLoggingKeyValueBytesSt
    ore.init(ChangeLoggingKeyValueBytesStore.java:40)
            at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.CachingKeyValueStore.init(Ca
    chingKeyValueStore.java:59)
            at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.InnerMeteredKeyValueStore.in
    it(InnerMeteredKeyValueStore.java:160)
            at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.MeteredKeyValueBytesStore.in
    it(MeteredKeyValueBytesStore.java:104)
            at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.AbstractTask.initializeS
    tateStores(AbstractTask.java:224)
            at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamTask.initialize(St
    reamTask.java:163)
            at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.AssignedTasks.initialize
    NewTasks(AssignedTasks.java:122)
            at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.TaskManager.updateNewAnd
    RestoringTasks(TaskManager.java:260)
            at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.runOnce(Str
    eamThread.java:813)
            at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.runLoop(Str
    eamThread.java:774)
            at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.run(StreamT
    hread.java:744)
```

Please note i have tried to look at other similar questions on the stackoverflow
and one in particular: [UnsatisfiedLinkError on Lib rocks DB dll when developing with Kafka Streams](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43742423/unsatisfiedlinkerror-on-lib-rocks-db-dll-when-developing-with-kafka-streams)
which has an excepted and up voted answer. I have tried to do same as mentioned in the answer but my problem still persists.