# KAFKA STREAM: UnsatisfiedLinkError on Lib Rocks DB

Tags: scala, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, rocksdb

I'm trying out Word Count problem with kafka streams. I am using Kafka 1.1.0 with scala version 2.11.12 and sbt version 1.1.4. I am getting following error:

```
Exception in thread "wordcount-application-d81ee069-9307-46f1-8e71-c9f777d2db64-StreamThread-1" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\librocksdbjni5439068356048679315.dll: À¦¥Y
at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1941)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1824)
at java.lang.Runtime.load0(Runtime.java:809)
at java.lang.System.load(System.java:1086)
at org.rocksdb.NativeLibraryLoader.loadLibraryFromJar(NativeLibraryLoader.java:78)
at org.rocksdb.NativeLibraryLoader.loadLibrary(NativeLibraryLoader.java:56)
at org.rocksdb.RocksDB.loadLibrary(RocksDB.java:64)
at org.rocksdb.RocksDB.<clinit>(RocksDB.java:35)
at org.rocksdb.Options.<clinit>(Options.java:25)
at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.RocksDBStore.openDB(RocksDBStore.java:116)
at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.RocksDBStore.init(RocksDBStore.java:167)
at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.ChangeLoggingKeyValueBytesStore.init(ChangeLoggingKeyValueBytesStore.java:40)
at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.CachingKeyValueStore.init(CachingKeyValueStore.java:63)
at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.InnerMeteredKeyValueStore.init(InnerMeteredKeyValueStore.java:160)
at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.MeteredKeyValueBytesStore.init(MeteredKeyValueBytesStore.java:102)
at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.AbstractTask.registerStateStores(AbstractTask.java:225)
at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamTask.initializeStateStores(StreamTask.java:162)
at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.AssignedTasks.initializeNewTasks(AssignedTasks.java:88)
at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.TaskManager.updateNewAndRestoringTasks(TaskManager.java:316)
at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.runOnce(StreamThread.java:789)
at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.runLoop(StreamThread.java:750)
at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.run(StreamThread.java:720)
```

I already tried solution given here [UnsatisfiedLinkError on Lib rocks DB dll when developing with Kafka Streams](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43742423/unsatisfiedlinkerror-on-lib-rocks-db-dll-when-developing-with-kafka-streams?noredirect=1&lq=1) .

Here is the code that i am trying out in scala.

```
object WordCountApplication {

  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val config: Properties = {
      val p = new Properties()
      p.put(StreamsConfig.APPLICATION_ID_CONFIG, "wordcount-application")
      p.put(StreamsConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "localhost:9092")
      p.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_KEY_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, Serdes.String().getClass)
      p.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_VALUE_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, Serdes.String().getClass)
      p
    }

    val builder: StreamsBuilder = new StreamsBuilder()
    val textLines: KStream[String, String] = builder.stream("streams-plaintext-input")

    val afterFlatMap: KStream[String, String] = textLines.flatMapValues(new ValueMapper[String,java.lang.Iterable[String]] {
      override def apply(value: String): lang.Iterable[String] = value.split("\\W+").toIterable.asJava
    })

    val afterGroupBy: KGroupedStream[String, String] = afterFlatMap.groupBy(new KeyValueMapper[String,String,String] {
      override def apply(key: String, value: String): String = value
    })


    val wordCounts: KTable[String, Long] = afterGroupBy
      .count(Materialized.as("counts-store").asInstanceOf[Materialized[String, Long, KeyValueStore[Bytes, Array[Byte]]]])
    wordCounts.toStream().to("streams-wordcount-output ", Produced.`with`(Serdes.String(), Serdes.Long()))

    val streams: KafkaStreams = new KafkaStreams(builder.build(), config)
    streams.start()

    Runtime.getRuntime.addShutdownHook(new Thread(
      new Runnable{
        override def run() = streams.close(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)}
    ))
  }
}
```

Build.sbt

```
name := "KafkaStreamDemo"

version := "0.1"

scalaVersion := "2.11.12"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.apache.kafka" %% "kafka" % "1.1.0",
  "org.apache.kafka" % "kafka-clients" % "1.1.0",
  "org.apache.kafka" % "kafka-streams" % "1.1.0",
  "ch.qos.logback" % "logback-classic" % "1.2.3"
)
```

If anyone has faced such problem, kindly help.

Comment: My development OS is Windows 7. I did try this same project on Windows 10 with same configuration of scala,kafka and sbt and it did worked. Any idea why this project is not working on windows 7.

Comment: I would assume that this is a RocksDB issue -- Kafka Streams only pulls in the dependency -- if RocksDB binding does not work on Window 7, there is nothing Kafka Streams can do about it. You could try to compile RocksDB on Windows 7 manually (following instructions on RocksDB Github page) and replace the dll file that Kafka Streams pulls in with your own build ddl to make it work. -- Overall, I would recommend to run Kafka Streams on a Unix/Linux based system though.

Comment: Thanks. I will try and let you know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally, I found answer which works. I followed [Unable to load rocksdbjni](https://github.com/facebook/rocksdb/issues/2531).

I did two things which worked for me.

1) I installed [Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2015](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48145).

2) Earlier, i was using rocksdb 5.7.3 with kafka-streams 1.1.0(rocksdb 5.7.3 comes by default with kafka-streams 1.1.0). I excluded rocksdb dependency from kafka-streams dependency and installed rocksdb 5.3.6. For reference, below is my built.sbt right now.

```
name := "KafkaStreamDemo"

version := "0.1"

scalaVersion := "2.12.5"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(

  "org.apache.kafka" %% "kafka" % "1.1.0",
  "org.apache.kafka" % "kafka-clients" % "1.1.0",
  "org.apache.kafka" % "kafka-streams" % "1.1.0" exclude("org.rocksdb","rocksdbjni"),
  "ch.qos.logback" % "logback-classic" % "1.2.3",
  "org.rocksdb" % "rocksdbjni" % "5.3.6"

)
```

Hope, it helps someone.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

In my case I was using kafka-streams:1.0.2. Changing the base docker image from alpine-jdk8:latest to openjdk:8-jre worked.

This link - https://github.com/docker-flink/docker-flink/pull/22 helped me arrive at this solution.