# Exception in thread "WordListenerService-process-applicationId-3e5d92bf-f503-4488-b367-d18deb1940c8-StreamThread-1" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError:

Tags: spring, spring-cloud-stream

I'm working on Spring Boot and Apache Kafka using Spring Cloud Stream. While running the code facing the below error.

```
Exception in thread "WordListenerService-process-applicationId-3e5d92bf-f503-4488-b367-d18deb1940c8-StreamThread-1" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /private/var/folders/g6/9m624n45627541g0xj6kssmw0000gn/T/librocksdbjni6807493407431942629.jnilib: dlopen(/private/var/folders/g6/9m624n45627541g0xj6kssmw0000gn/T/librocksdbjni6807493407431942629.jnilib, 0x0001): tried: '/private/var/folders/g6/9m624n45627541g0xj6kssmw0000gn/T/librocksdbjni6807493407431942629.jnilib' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'x86_64', need 'arm64e')), '/usr/lib/librocksdbjni6807493407431942629.jnilib' (no such file)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(ClassLoader.java:2452)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:2508)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:2704)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:2637)
    at java.base/java.lang.Runtime.load0(Runtime.java:745)
    at java.base/java.lang.System.load(System.java:1873)
    at org.rocksdb.NativeLibraryLoader.loadLibraryFromJar(NativeLibraryLoader.java:78)
    at org.rocksdb.NativeLibraryLoader.loadLibrary(NativeLibraryLoader.java:56)
    at org.rocksdb.RocksDB.loadLibrary(RocksDB.java:64)
    at org.rocksdb.RocksDB.<clinit>(RocksDB.java:35)
    at org.rocksdb.DBOptions.<clinit>(DBOptions.java:21)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.RocksDBStore.openDB(RocksDBStore.java:130)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.RocksDBStore.init(RocksDBStore.java:224)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.WrappedStateStore.init(WrappedStateStore.java:48)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.ChangeLoggingKeyValueBytesStore.init(ChangeLoggingKeyValueBytesStore.java:42)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.WrappedStateStore.init(WrappedStateStore.java:48)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.CachingKeyValueStore.init(CachingKeyValueStore.java:61)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.WrappedStateStore.init(WrappedStateStore.java:48)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.MeteredKeyValueStore.lambda$init$0(MeteredKeyValueStore.java:101)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.metrics.StreamsMetricsImpl.maybeMeasureLatency(StreamsMetricsImpl.java:836)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.MeteredKeyValueStore.init(MeteredKeyValueStore.java:101)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorStateManager.registerStateStores(ProcessorStateManager.java:199)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StateManagerUtil.registerStateStores(StateManagerUtil.java:76)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamTask.initializeIfNeeded(StreamTask.java:211)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.TaskManager.tryToCompleteRestoration(TaskManager.java:426)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.runOnce(StreamThread.java:660)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.runLoop(StreamThread.java:551)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.run(StreamThread.java:510)
9:39:59 PM: Execution finished ':StreamingAggregatesApplication.main()'.
```

WordListeningBinders.java

```
public interface WordListenerBinding {
    @Input("words-input-channel")
    KStream<String, String> wordsInputStream();
}
```

WordListenerService.java

```
@Service
@Log4j2
@EnableBinding(WordListenerBinding.class)
public class WordListenerService {

    @StreamListener("words-input-channel")
    public void process(KStream<String, String> input) {

        KStream<String, String> wordStream = input
                .flatMapValues(value -> Arrays.asList(value.toLowerCase().split(" ")));

        wordStream.groupBy((key, value) -> value)
                .count()
                .toStream()
                .peek((k, v) -> log.info("Word: {} Count: {}", k, v));
    }
}
```

application.yml

```
spring:
  cloud:
    stream:
      bindings:
        words-input-channel:
          destination: streaming-words-topic
      kafka:
        streams:
          binder:
            brokers:  localhost:9092
            configuration:
              commit.interval.ms: 10000
              state.dir: state-store
              default:
                key:
                  serde: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serdes$StringSerde
                value:
                  serde: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serdes$StringSerde
```

Answer (score -1):

Judging from the stack trace this error has nothing to do with Spring or Spring Cloud Stream. Also, it seems pretty common and basic search renders many answers (e.g., issue with version of java libraries etc. . .). Here is an example of just one of such answers - [KAFKA STREAM: UnsatisfiedLinkError on Lib Rocks DB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49977787/kafka-stream-unsatisfiedlinkerror-on-lib-rocks-db)

Additionally, I see that you are using `@StreamListener`. The annotation-based programming model has been deprecated for several years and is being removed from the next version of Spring Cloud Stream, so please address it following the [functional programming model](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/3.1.5/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream.html#_programming_model)